# What is the best way to work with a Cosmos Document db? EF Core vs Cosmos SDK

Tags: entity-framework, sdk, azure-cosmosdb

Microsoft provides two ways of working with cosmos dbs in C#/.NET.

One can either use Entity Framework(EF) Core, which makes use of the cosmos SDK behind the scenes and allows you to use EF with Cosmos.

This last point could be seen as positive or negative depending on if you want to use EF vs Dapper or whatever, but for my use case, I would prefer to use EF unless given a good reason not to.

Microsoft themselves has not made any statement I can find on which should be used or why. (I Assume this is a .NET Core project)

Comment: The recommendation from the Cosmos DB team is to use their SDK versus EF. Particularly for performance. Also the EF support is Preview only whereas the SDK's are GA.

Comment: Do you have a link to that comment? @MarkBrown

Comment: @horizon He does work for Microsoft.

Comment: I work on the Cosmos DB team so you can quote me. :)

Comment: @MarkBrown does this argument still hold today, or is ef core preferred?

Comment: Still true. The Cosmos EF provider wraps the native Cosmos SDK so the native Cosmos SDK will ALWAYS perform better. Also any new features will always be supported by the native SDK before EF.  Bottom line, if you want the best performance and support, use the native SDK. Frankly with a NoSQL database it makes zero sense to use any type of ORM given a NoSQL database allows you to serialize objects directly without any mapping layer.

Answer (score 5):

EF Core works only for SQL API of Cosmos DB as of now. So, If you are using other APIs, you cannot use EF Core.

Also, Take a look at other limitations of EF Core Azure Cosmos DB Provider Limitations at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/limitations

We used Cosmos DB SDK which is quite flexible and the performance is also good.

Answer (score 3):

After an experience with Cosmonaut package, EF Core and SDK I have to say that Ef Core is focused on relational mapping. Witch Document DB you need to focus on Json serialization. Ef Core model configuration feels cumbersome and limiting for document DB interaction - You have to configure things that just works while serializing. Both Cosmonaut and SDK allow focusing on serialization which in most cases just works. Cosmonaut is a convenient facade on top of SDK - but looks dead at the moment so I recommend SDK.